# How to make nunjuck templates compatible with LaTex?

Tags: node.js, latex, nunjucks

I have a Node.js script that analises some data and generates a report in HTML using nunjuck templates.

Now, I want to also generate a report in LaTeX. However, the syntax used by nunjucks conflicts with that of LaTeX. For instance, the string `{#` appears very often in any Latex template.

How can I configure the nunjucks environment to instruct it to use different syntax?

Comment: Try http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#customizing-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!